# Error during upgrade to Magento 2.1 from 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, composer

Since a couple of days i try to upgrade my "native" Magento 2.0.7
I use composer as suggested by documentation :

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update;
composer update;
php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
```

But when Magento try to update "Magento_Cms" native extension, I got a :

```
The page URL key contains capital letters or disallowed symbols.
```

Any help ?

EDIT : Here the solution I use to by pass the problem :

- Edit file vendor/magento/module-cms/Setup/UpgradeData.php
- Search for method public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){}
- And just comment the content of the :

  `if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
      /*
      [...]
      */
  }`

I don't know why setup is entering in this condition, because my current version is 2.0.7 !
Maybe this post will help someone... (you can reset the updated file after installation).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the function in `/var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Page.php`:

```
if (!$this->isValidPageIdentifier($object)) {
  //throw new LocalizedException(
  //    __('The page URL key contains capital letters or disallowed symbols.')
  //);
}
```

Or you could try to make sure your magento runs on a top level domain, I guess `http://magento` would throw an exception but http://magento.company.org would work. But as I'm also in the development step I will try this myself a bit later.

Comment: That's what i did the first time the error occured, but a "corrupted" page has been created in DB.