# Area code not set

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.7

I have been trying to get around this  Area code not set error and have references the others in here, but have a issue tracking it down.

i have been trying to upgrade 2.0.7 to 2.1.0 and when i get to the point where i run:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade -vvv

I get this as the error.

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]
>     Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.
>
> Exception trace:
>    () at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:176
>    Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:50
>    Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:130
>    Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:14
>    Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->__construct() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:89
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/J2t/Rewardpoints/Observer/ProcessSaveModel.php:21
>    J2t\Rewardpoints\Observer\ProcessSaveModel->execute() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:73
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:61
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:66
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php:95
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:800
>    Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterSave() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:818
>    Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->processAfterSaves() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:408
>    Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:631
>    Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Setup/Recurring.php:108
>    Magento\Indexer\Setup\Recurring->install() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:871
>    Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:779
>    Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php:89
>    Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
>    Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento:23
>
> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>     Area code is not set
>
> Exception trace:
>    () at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:139
>    Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:174
>    Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:50
>    Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:130
>    Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:14
>    Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->__construct() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:89
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:126
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:53
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
>    Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/J2t/Rewardpoints/Observer/ProcessSaveModel.php:21
>    J2t\Rewardpoints\Observer\ProcessSaveModel->execute() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:73
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:61
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:66
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php:95
>    Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:800
>    Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterSave() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:818
>    Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->processAfterSaves() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:408
>    Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:631
>    Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Setup/Recurring.php:108
>    Magento\Indexer\Setup\Recurring->install() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:871
>    Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:779
>    Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php:89
>    Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
>    Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento:23
>
> setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

So if anyone can assist with where to look, this would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look here first: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/142652104930/magento-2-fixing-area-code-not-set-exceptions
I don't know if this will work for you, as in the case described he was making a customer CLI module.
Also, looking through your stack trace, i don't see any 3rd party modules. Are you using any? Those are the next trigger for this kind of error. That was what I ran into a few weeks back:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128658/magento-2-area-code-not-set-warning-in-3rd-party-module

Comment: there are, two,  so I will back them out and see where this goes.

Comment: Something else that popped in to my head, make sure you are clearing the folders in /var as you test. If a error is kicking in the var/generation, even if you fix the issue in the code, this folder is looked to when you perform any other CLI commands, and can trip you up as you go.

Comment: forsure did that, so what i did end up doing is disabling the J2t module, and run again.

Comment: I ran into a small error
But when Magento try to update "Magento_Cms" native extension, I got a :

The page URL key contains capital letters or disallowed symbols.

but following this 

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123364/error-during-upgrade-to-magento-2-1-from-2-0-7

fixed it and shazaam, i am upgraded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look here:

> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/**app/code/J2t/Rewardpoints/Observer/ProcessSaveModel.php:21**

Looks like this module is trying to grab the Object Manager which might be triggering the error if that area code is not set. In my comment, i linked to a solution i found to this error for an extension i was using. Might help you out here as the call to the Object Manager is happening in an Observer.

Here is that link again: [Magento 2 "Area code not set" warning in 3rd party module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128658/magento-2-area-code-not-set-warning-in-3rd-party-module)

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case, I don't see any third part modules from the exception trace. All lines from exception trace are Magento\Framework\ObjectManager..... Can I trace more errors from log excep this -vvv option?

Comment: That's the first place to start. I have seen this issue come up for other reasons outside of this specific question. It would be worth trying to get a more verbose report and then posting a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this issue running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, and the exception was thrown by `module-config`.

`Area code is not set {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\State\\InvalidTransitionException(code: 0): Area code is not set at /magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Importer.php:137`

It turned out that I had some settings in `app/etc/env.php` that the configuration importer did not like. Setting a breakpoint on that line showed me which data was trying to be updated, and removing that from `app/etc/env.php` fixed the issue for me.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Added a var_export() on *vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Importer.php* to see what it was buzzy with.

```
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_export($data);
        throw new InvalidTransitionException(__('%1', $e->getMessage()), $e);
```

Then it returned some settings from my app/ect/env.php

```
array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'dev' => 
    array (
      'debug' => 
      array (
        'debug_logging' => '0',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Removed it and it works again.